# Conflict between mathtools and MnSymbol

Tags: incompatibility, mathtools

When I run `latex` on the following file, it terminates successfully, and produces the expected result:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fleqn,tbtags]{mathtools}
%% \usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
$$ x \xhookrightarrow{\gamma} y $$
\end{document}
```

But if I uncomment the commented-out line, I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \lhook
                  \joinrel \relbar
l.6 $$ x \xhookrightarrow{\gamma}
                                  y $$
?
```

Is there any way to get around this?  (Of course, the example above does not require MnSymbol, but I do need it, along with mathtools, for what I'm working on.)

FWIW, here are the versions I have of the packages mentioned in the example:

```
Package: amsmath 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
Package: mathtools 2011/02/12 v1.10 mathematical typesetting tools
Package: MnSymbol 2007/01/21 v1.4 support for the MnSymbol font
```

Thanks!

PS: ironically enough, the only reason I have for using MnSymbol is to use its arrow definitions, as in

```
$$
\begin{matrix}
X & & \xrightarrow{h} & & Y \\
  & {\scriptstyle f} \lhooksearrow & & \rhookswarrow {\scriptstyle g} & \\
  & & Z & & \\
\end{matrix}
$$
```

to produce commutative diagrams like:

[image: results from latex code above]

...whose layout I find *just barely* acceptable (the arrows are too short, and don't necessarily lie right on, and/or parallel to, the lines connecting their source and target symbols; the spacing between these symbols is not always the best; etc.).  IOW, if there is a better way to produce diagrams like these, possibly without needing MnSymbol, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: I would not create diagrams like that, use the `xy` package or use `tikz` (much better look)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, **MnSymbol** undefines `\lhook` because it provides ready made "hooked arrows", while `\lhook` is used for building them from "normal arrows" in the default math fonts.

Just write, after loading **MnSymbol**,

```
\let\originallhook\lhook
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\let\lhook\originallhook
```

but what's obtained with `\xhookrightarrow` won't be perfect. A bit better is

```
\let\originallhook\lhook
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\newcommand{\lhook}{\mathrel{\raise.018ex\hbox{$\originallhook$}}}
```

On the other hand, you should look at the specialized package Xy-pic or at the more general TikZ for building diagrams.

Comment: After reading your reply, I commented out the offending line in MnSymbol (where it sets `\lhook` to undefined), and the program ran without any apparent problems.  What would be the harm in commenting out this line?  (I don't understand why MnSymbol includes this line in the first place; even if it provides alternatives to `\lhook`, going to the extent of actually *removing* `\lhook` seems gratuitous.)

Comment: @kjo The reason is that the default hook just doesn't mix well with the provided arrows. Don't modify packages: in case of an update you'll lose your changes. Instead do as suggested in my edited answer.

Comment: @kjo The reason is that the default hook just doesn't mix well with the provided arrows. Don't modify packages: in case of an update you'll lose your changes. Instead do as suggested in my edited answer.

Comment: ok, but at least i'd like to report this as a bug in MnSymbol.  i need to figure out how to do that...