# \xhookrightarrow "undefined" even though I have mathtools loaded

Tags: math-mode, arrows, mathtools

Edit: turns out this is a duplicate question. There's a conflict with another package that undefines the `\lhook` command:
[Conflict between mathtools and MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28656/conflict-between-mathtools-and-mnsymbol)

---

Pretty simple question, though I don't know how hard it'll be to troubleshoot. I have the `mathtools` package primed in a style file that I've loaded into my document (using `\usepackage`). In my document, I've tried to call the `\xhookrightarrow` command in an equation environment to typeset an inclusion arrow with a label above it, but Overleaf tells me that the control sequence is undefined

[image]
and typesets a normal `\xrightarrow` instead

[image]

The code in question:

```
\begin{equation*}
     A \xhookrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C
\end{equation*}
```

and the initial info of the error message from Overleaf

```
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
Learn more
<argument> \lhook 
                  \joinrel \relbar 
l.442         A \xhookrightarrow{f}
                                    B \xrightarrow{g} C
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Anyone have any idea what's gone wrong here? Or perhaps someone can help me with some quick code to redefine the `\xhookrightarrow` command from scratch, and hope that works instead?

Comment: If you click the red number next to the "Recompile" button, you can see the actual error message.  If Sebastiano's answer doesn't help you out, please turn this into a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), so that we can see what you're actually trying.

Comment: @campa oh sorry, I did actually use `\usepackage` in my code, editing the question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to inform you that there is no two direct commands in `LaTeX`, to my memory, such as `\Mod` and `\PU`. I don't know if they were declaredin the preamble that you didn't add as newcommands. Then I think that your error message is just due to these two nonexistent commands `\Mod` and `\PU` and without to have a complete `tex` code. The following solution will definitely work with `Overleaf`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    B_{n} \xhookrightarrow{i_*} \mathrm{Mod}(S_{0,m};\vec k) \xrightarrow{\rho_{\vec k}} \mathrm{PU}(1,m-3)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated my question to get rid of my custom user defined math operators. The problem persists.

Comment: @EthanDlugie You use my code.

Comment: I figured out that there's a clash between mathtools and MnSymbol. I closed my question and linked to another thread that resolves the issue. Thanks for your help though!